# How to get user clicked view layer of SVG image using Macaw library in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, svg

I am using Macaw library to show SVG image in my application, but not able to color particular SVG view on user interaction.

I am able to add color to the SVG file by adding node tags statically which are there in SVG file. But how to get these node tags dynamically on run time ?

My code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    svgView.fileName = "svgFileName"


    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.tapBlurButton(_:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
   }


@objc func tapBlurButton(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
   changeNodeColor(nodeTag: "AQW-12")
}

func changeNodeColor(nodeTag : String) {
    let nodeShape = self.svgView.node.nodeBy(tag: nodeTag) as! Shape
    nodeShape.fill = Color.red
}
```

Comment: check the isUserInteractionEnabled property of your svgView

Comment: Interaction is enabled. Just need to figure out to get tag node at runtime.